# Find the domain and range of the function : $f(x) = \sqrt{\lfloor x\rfloor -x}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, elementary-functions

Find the domain and range of the function : $f(x) = \sqrt{\lfloor x \rfloor -x}$ where $\lfloor x \rfloor $ is the floor function (greatest integer function)

This is how I did it : $f(x) = \sqrt{\lfloor x \rfloor -x}$

For $f(x)$ to be defined, $\lfloor x \rfloor-x$ must be greater than or equal to $0$

So, $\lfloor x \rfloor-x \geq 0$

So, $x \leq \lfloor x \rfloor$

$x$ is never less than $\lfloor x \rfloor$ but it can be equal to it if $x \in \Bbb Z$


So, shouldn't the $domain$ of $f$ be $\Bbb  Z$?


In my textbook, the $domain$ of $f$ is given to be $\varnothing$ but I think that it is defined for all $x \in \Bbb Z$ and for all $x \in \Bbb Z$, the value of $f(x)$ is $0$, so in my opinion, the $range$ of $f$ should be **{0}** which is also given to be $\varnothing$ in my textbook

I have one more question, if for any real function $f$, $Domain(f) = \varnothing$, then is $Range(f) = \varnothing$ always true as well? I think so...

Thanks

Comment: is $[x] = \lceil x \rceil$, the ceiling function?

Comment: It's the floor function

Comment: The code to typeset the floor function is `\lfloor \rfloor`, and the empty set is obtained with `\emptyset`, or better, `\varnothing`.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks

Comment: But can't we denote empty set just by $\phi$?

Comment: @Bernard What is your opinion on the answer?

Comment: I quite agree with it (except the phi· ;o))

Comment: Well, I changed it now...:)

Comment: @Bernard I guess you learn something everyday :)

Comment: Books have typos.  Your reasoning is very clear and thorough.   ANd we can just do an example $f(5) = \sqrt{[5]-5} = \sqrt {5-5}=\sqrt 0 = 0$ is perfectly well defined so $5 \in $ domain and domain $\ne \emptyset$.  ... But your analysis is *perfect* $\sqrt{[x]-x}$ is well defined precisely when $[x]-x \ge 0$ or when $[x]\ge x$.  Is is always the case that $[x]\le x < [x]+1$ with equality holding precisely with $x\in \mathbb Z$, the function is defined iff $x\le[x]\le x<[x]+1$ which occurs iff $x=[x]$ iff $x\in \mathbb Z$.  ... You are 100% correct.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks, it was really motivating as well :)

Comment: Also, there was another question : $f(x) = cos(log x)$, then what is the value of : $f(x)f(y)-\dfrac{1}{2}[f(\dfrac{x}{y}) + f(xy)]$? I have only done $10th$ grade Trigonometry yet and I don't know much about it other than the three standard identities and their applications. Is this knowledge enough to solve this question or does it require something unknown to me yet?

Comment: If you’re looking for simplification, you would need to know some log properties.

Comment: I do know some of them, but don't know how to apply them in questions tho...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re correct. The domain would be $\mathbb Z$, and for every integer input the output will be $0$.

If the domain is $\varnothing$, then the range is $\varnothing$ as well because the function cannot map to any value.

Comment: Thank You......

Answer (score 1):

$\bullet$ Any real number $x$ can be written as $\lfloor{x}\rfloor+h$ with $h$ a real number in $[0; 1)$.

$\bullet$ Since $\sqrt {X}$ is only defined for input $X\geq 0$, the function $f(x)= \sqrt{\lfloor{x}\rfloor - x}$ requires $\lfloor{x}\rfloor - x \geq 0$.

Now 
$\lfloor{x}\rfloor - x \geq 0$

$\iff \lfloor{x}\rfloor - (\lfloor{x}\rfloor+h)\geq 0$

$\iff- h \geq 0$

$\iff - h = 0$ OR $ -h \gt 0$

$\iff - h = 0$

$ \iff h = 0$

Note : the second disjunct is an impossibility :  since $h\in [0; 1)$ , $-h\in (-1; 0]$, and hence, cannot be strictly greater than $0$. Logic allows to eliminate an impossible disjunct : $P\lor False \equiv P$.

So, the function only takes inputs of the form $x= \lfloor{x}\rfloor + 0= \lfloor{x}\rfloor$.

The domain of  function $f$ is the range of the floor function, namely $\mathbb Z$.

$\bullet$ For any integer input $x, \lfloor{x}\rfloor =x $, so , substituting ,

$f(x)= \sqrt {\lfloor{x}\rfloor - x} = \sqrt { x-x} = \sqrt 0=0$.

So , the range of $f$ is {0}.

---

As to the question : what is the range of a function if the domain is $\emptyset$?

A function $f$ from $A$ to $B$ is, before all,  a relation from $A$ to $B$ , hence a subset of the cartesian product $A\times B$ ( = set of all ordered pairs $(x,y)$ with $x\in A$ and $y\in B$).

So, if a function $f$ is a relation from $\emptyset$ to any set $S$, then it is a subset of $\emptyset\times S = \emptyset$.

Note that , since any subset of the emptyset is empty, $f = \emptyset$.

The range of $f$ is ( by definition)  the set of all $y_{\in S}$ such that $y=f(x)$ ***for some*** $x$ in domain$(f)$.

Since domain$(f)$ is empty , range$(f)$ is empty.

Comment: That's a good answer, but in my opinion, what I did might have been sufficient to find the domain and range, right?

Comment: Yes, I also think that what you have done is correct and that your answer does the job.

Comment: Thanks :) .....